# Почему функция вызывается два раза в nextJS/ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, nextjs

#### page.js

```
'use client'
import { useState } from "react"
import Task from "./components/task"

Array.prototype.appEnd = function(element){
  this[this.length] = element
}

export default function Main(){
  const [arr, setArr] = useState([1,1])
  arr.appEnd('2') // <-- вызывается 2 раза
  console.log(arr) // <-- вызывается 2 раза
  return(
      <>
      </>
  )
}
```

#### Консоль

```
page.js:12 (3) [1, 1, '2']
page.js:12 (4) [1, 1, '2', '2']
```

Пробовал React stict mode, не помогло

Comment: https://react.dev/reference/react/StrictMode#fixing-bugs-found-by-double-rendering-in-development
Это специально. Компонент должен нормально работать если его вызывают много раз. Если это не так, то это ошибка в компоненте и разработчик должен её решить. Собственно strict mode это и делает, показывает разработчику где он написал плохой код.

Comment: P.S. а зачем appEnd если это просто push?

Comment: Начать стоит с логичного вопроса - почему она вообще вызывается? Где, кто и как использует функцию Main? В показанном вами коде она никак не используется

Comment: @AlexeyTen это я и так знаю. С push таже ситуация думал вдруг так сработает

Comment: @andreymal она вызывается где-то внутри nextjs фреймворка

Comment: 1. **НИКОГДА** не мутируйте прототипы встроенных классов 2. **НИКОГДА** не мутируйте стейты в `React` 3. Поделитесь кодом, где вызывается компонент `Main`